# How can I match the values of one dataframe(more than column) with values of another dataframe(more than one column)?

Tags: python, pandas

df1 :

```
    Symbol           Aliases
0   MLH1             COCA2, FCC2, HNPCC, HNPCC2, hMLH1
1   MSH2             COCA1, FCC1, HNPCC, HNPCC1, LCFS2
2   CCAT2            LINC00873, NCCP1
3   MACC1            7A5, SH3BP4L
```

here, Aliases can have NaN values.

df2 :

```
   Symbol_1        Symbol_2
0  NaN             DHX9
1  COCA1           MSH2
2  H2AC18          NaN
3  NCCP1           NaN
```

I want result as one list which contains all the symbols which are same in df1 and df2.

```
same_list = [MSH2, CCAT2]
```

If df2['Symbol_1', 'Symbol_2'] matches df1['Symbol'] it will print Symbol but if it matches df1['Aliases'] it will print the corresponding Symbol from df1.

We can see that NCCP1 matches with df1['Aliases'] but it will print the corresponding Symbol i.e. CCAT2

Answer (score 0):

You can use `flatten()` and `set()` to obtain your values.

If `df1` is:

```
  Symbol                        Aliases
0   MLH1  COCA2,FCC2,HNPCC,HNPCC2,hMLH1
1   MSH2  COCA1,FCC1,HNPCC,HNPCC1,LCFS2
2  CCAT2                LINC00873,NCCP1
3  MACC1                    7A5,SH3BP4L
```

and `df2` is:

```
Symbol_1 Symbol_2
0      NaN     DHX9
1    COCA1     MSH2
2   H2AC18      NaN
3    NCCP1      NaN
```

then this script:

```
df1.Aliases = df1.Aliases.str.split(',')
s1 = set(df1.explode('Aliases').values.flatten())
s2 = set(df2.values.flatten())
print(s1 & s2)
```

Prints:

```
{'NCCP1', 'COCA1', 'MSH2'}
```

Comment: But, I am getting the error " 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'explode' "

Comment: And what can I do if I want the result as      same_list = [MSH2, CCAT2]                           If Symbol_1 and Symbol_2 of df2 matches with Symbol of df1 then Symbol will be printed and if it matches with Aliases of df1, then I need the corresponding Symbol will be printed